# When using latexdiff, is there a way to generate a list of pages that contain changes?

Tags: latexdiff

I have tried redefining `\DIFaddbegin` et al. with `todo` ([todonotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes)) or `index` ([makeidx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeidx)) calls by using the preamble below, but I'm not getting anything.

```
%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}
\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1}   %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}   %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE

\renewcommand{\DIFaddbegin}{\index{added}}
\renewcommand{\DIFdelbegin}{\index{deleted}}
\renewcommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{\index{added}}
\renewcommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{\index{deleted}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Is `diffpdf` an option?